# for what values of N element N is $3^{n+1}>n^4$

Tags: logic, induction, education

So I'm doing homework for my logic class... 
For what values of n element of natural numbers is $3^{n+1}>n^4$ and we are supposed to use induction. This is what I have so far...

Proof: The inequality holds for n=1.  Since $3^2>1^4= 9>1$. Assume $3^{k+1}>k$, where $k\geq 1$. We show $3^{k+2}>(k+1)^4$

$3^{k+2}=3^2+3^k>3k^4=k^4+k^4+k^4...$ I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Note:  if $n=3$ the inequality is false.

Comment: $3^{k+2}=3^2\cdot 3^k\neq 3^2+3^k$

Comment: we need $$n \ge 4$$

Comment: Use $3>\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^4$ for $ n \geq 4$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $3^{n+1}>n^4$ is true for $n=1,\ 2$ and all $n\ge5$. (The inequality is false for $n=3$ and $n=4$ because $81\not>81$ and $243\not>256$.)

We can prove the inequality for $n\ge5$ by induction.

The base case ($n=5$) is true: $3^6>5^4, \ \ 729>625$.

Now suppose the inequality is true for some $k\ge5$:
$$
3^{k+1} > k^4. \tag{1}
$$
But
$$
3^{k+2}=3^{k+1}+2\cdot3^{k+1}, \quad\mbox{ while }\quad
(k+1)^4 = k^4 + 4k^3+ 6k^2+ 4k+ 1,
$$
and for every $k\ge5$ we have
$$
2\cdot3^{k+1} > 2\cdot k^4 \ge 2\cdot5k^3> 4k^3+ 6k^2+ 4k+ 1
$$
by hypothesis $(1)$. Thus we have $3^{k+2}>(k+1)^4$; our induction step is completed.

Therefore, by the principle of mathematical induction, our inequality $$3^{n+1}>n^4$$ is true for all $n\ge5$.